# Is it possible to write a user function that checks if passed in value is in results of a second query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to write a user function that takes input, and returns whether or not that input is present in another query. Basically this

```
.create-or-alter function with (folder = "foo") IsPresent(userInput: string) {
        toscalar(
            OtherTable
            | where x == userInput
            | summarize count()
        )
    )
}
```

So I can do something like this in my base query

```
Foo
| extend isPresent = IsPresent(x)
```

This results in the error  *Semantic error: '' has the following semantic error: Unresolved reference binding: 'userInput'.*

As a workaround I tried changing IsPresent to return a make_list(x), and then in my base query do this

```
let vals = IsPresent();
Foo
| extend isPresent = vals contains x
```

which does work, but is incredibly slow.

Is there a correct way to do this? I'm trying to avoid writing a join in my base query; i'd like something simple and re-usable. I've been searching but can't find any examples of someone trying to do something similar

Answer (score 1):

you could try rewriting your function to take tabular arguments, and then use [the `invoke` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/invokeoperator). an example can be found below.

```
.set T <| range x from 1 to 10 step 1  // a dummy data set

.set Other_T <| range y from 5 to 10000 step 1 // another dummy data set

.create-or-alter function IsPresent (T1:(userInput:long), T2:(y:long)) {
    let values = T2 | project y;
    T1
    | extend is_present = userInput in (values)
}

T
| project-rename userInput = x
| invoke IsPresent(Other_T)
```

-->

```
| userInput | is_present |
|-----------|------------|
| 1         | 0          |
| 2         | 0          |
| 3         | 0          |
| 4         | 0          |
| 5         | 1          |
| 6         | 1          |
| 7         | 1          |
| 8         | 1          |
| 9         | 1          |
| 10        | 1          |
```